# Using NSXMLParser to get an attribute in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

Is there a special way that you have to call `attributeDict` where the string contains a dash?

I'm trying to get the period name below:

```
<time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="12hourly">
     <layout-key>k-p12h-n13-1</layout-key>
          <start-valid-time period-name="Veterans Day">2015-11-11T06:00:00-05:00</start-valid-time>
```

Using

```
if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("start-valid-time") {
    var test = attributeDict["period-name"]!
    print(elementName)
    print(attributeDict)
}
```

i can see that the attribute name in the playground is the same key I'm asking for but it doesn't return? It has to be something weird with the `"-"` I'm thinking?

Edit:  this might be a Swift issue because using string interpolation returns the string:

```
let test = ("\(attributeDict["period-name"])")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `NSXMLParser` and it's attributeDict is an Objective-C API, and `NSDictionary` forces key/values to conform to the `NSCopying` protocol, that requires an `NSObject`.  Because of that you can't go directly from `NSObject` to `String`, passing through `NSString` is mandatory, so:

```
if let periodAsNSString: NSString = attributeDict["period-name"] {
     let periodAsString: String = periodAsNSString as String
}
```

Finally got the value into a String